# Email notification after registration in Wordpress

Tags: email, user-registration, notifications

I would like the site's administrator doesn't receive a new user's registration email when the administrator himself uses the admin interface to add a user.

How can I limit sending a email only when a user completes the registration form ?

```
// If the registration form was completed by a user ...

add_action( 'user_register', 'user_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function user_registration_save( $user_id ) {
   $to = '';
   $subject = 'New register with the form';
   $message .= "Identifiant : " . $user->user_login . "\r\n\r\n";
   $message .= "E-mail : " . $user->user_email;
   wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

Comment: you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-new-user-notifications

Comment: Hmm, but wait. Do you use your custom code to send these notifications? You don't use the built-in `wp_send_new_user_notifications` function?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Yes, I use this code. But, It's probably better to use your solution to send the notification mail. Thank you !